# how to add matrices as values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matrix, nlp

I have a dictionary which its values are matrices and its keys are the most frequent words in the train file. I have a test file, I have to see if the words in each line of that are in the dictionary it gets their values which are matrices and add the matrices and then divide them to the number of words. the answer should be one matrix. I tried "sum(val)" but it doesn't add them together. How can I do it? (The file contains a Persian sentence, a tab and then an English word). The output of the dictionary is as like as below:

[image]

```
keys = [p[0] for p in freq.most_common(4)]            
array = numpy.array([[wordVector[0,:]] , [wordVector[1,:]],    [wordVector[2,:]], [wordVector[3,:]]])
dic = dict(zip(keys, zip(array)))
#print (dic)

# test part
with open ("test2.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as f2:
    for line in f2:
        line = line.split("\t")
        lin = line[0].split()
        for i in lin:
            for key, val in dic.items():
                if i == key:
                    print ((sum(val))/
```

Answer (score 0):

The `val` is an `numpy.array` and you can use the sum() function: `val.sum()`

Comment: there is this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sum'

Comment: ok, I see the values are tuples with one element. Then it's `val[0].sum()`. But why do you have a zip(array) in the creation of your dictionary? I think `dict(zip(keys, array))` is enough.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it returns -1.37638192047
-1.05146222424 which is not the correct adding number. the correct answer should be [-2.2269 , -0.2008]. How can I access that?

Comment: it should add [-0.8505, -0.5257] + [-1.3764, 0.3249]

Comment: If you want to sum by columns you use: `numpy.sum(val[0], axis=0)` and for sum by rows: `numpy.sum(val[0], axis=1)`

Comment: I think there is a mistake in my dictionary making. again there is error when using axis = 1:     out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds